# SQL get last rows after a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say we have this message log table which stores conversations between two people

```
message         own_account reply_batch unix_timestamp  conversation_id
Hi              f           f          1543452938       5b43d
Hello           t           t          1543453562       5b43d
How are you?    f           f          1543453814       5b43d
good and you?   t           t          1543454118       5b43d
I'm good too.   f           f          1543454344       5b43d
Are you home?   f           f          1543454950       5b43d
```

What would the SQL be to return the rows after our last `own_account` set to true which in this case is "good and you?" I want to get the last messages right after the last `own_account` message. In this case we should get two rows back.

```
I'm good too.   f           f          1543454344       5b43d
Are you home?   f           f          1543454950       5b43d
```

Each conversation is tracked with the `conversation_id`

And if the only messages in the conversion is from them, I want those messages returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will scan the table twice, but will be fast if there us an index on `(cinversation_id, unix_timestamp)`:

```
WITH lastmsg AS (
   SELECT max(unix_timestamp) AS ts
   FROM messages
   WHERE own_account
     AND conversation_id = '5b43d')
SELECT * FROM messages
CROSS JOIN lastmsg
WHERE unix_timestamp > COALESCE(ts, '-infinity'::timestamptz)
  AND conversation_id = '5b43d';
```

Comment: I'm doing this for specific conversions, so I also need to use `where conversation_id = '5b43d'`

Comment: I modified the answer.

Comment: Thank you, works great, can you also show how it would be done if I only want the last message? so in this case it would be "Are you home?"

Comment: @Arya You should not change your question after people have already answered.  Also, your new question may not be well defined, if `own_account` happens to be true for the last record.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I just found out an issue, if the conversion does not contain any messages from `own_reply` then their message is not returned. So if the conversation has only their messages, then nothing is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option.  The first count `cnt1` is a cumumative count of the number of own account records which are true.  The second count is a table level total of own account records which are true.  The records we want to target are those for which these two counts are equal.

```
SELECT message, own_account, reply_batch, unix_timestamp, conversation_id
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN own_account = 't' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY unix_timestamp) AS cnt1,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN own_account = 't' THEN 1 END) OVER () AS cnt2
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE conversation_id = '5b43d'
) t
WHERE cnt1 = cnt2 AND own_account = 'f';
```

Comment: I'm doing this for specific conversions, so I also need to use where `conversation_id = '5b43d'` I also add `AND conversation_id = '5b43d'` to the end of the query?

Comment: @Arya Just add that restriction inside the subquery.  The rest should work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . I find this logic a bit more complicated than necessary -- I had to think for a bit on why the counts should be the same.  You might check out my answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The downside of being proficient with SQL is that one my blast off a query which to the author seems easy, but might not be the most direct way of answering.

Answer (score 0):

I like Tim's answer . . . sort of.  I think this version is clearer:

```
SELECT message, own_account, reply_batch, unix_timestamp, conversation_id
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             MAX(unix_timestamp) FILTER (WHERE own_account = 't') OVER 
                 (PARTITION BY conversation_id
                  ORDER BY unix_timestamp
                 ) AS my_max_unix_timestamp
      FROM t
      WHERE conversation_id = '5b43d'
     ) t
WHERE unix_timestamp > my_max_unix_timestamp;
```

This pretty much is a direct translation of your question.  The subquery calculates the last timestamp for "my message" for each conversation (or for a given conversation).  The outer `where` then selects messages that are later than that one.